# JQuery AJAX Get request with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, rest, getjson

I call the following ajax from a form:

```
$.ajax({ 
data: JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray()),  //an array  [{"name":"myform","value":"entered value"}] 
 dataType: 'json', 
 type: 'POST',                           
 url:'products/id/code',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 success:  function(json){
 $("#container").html(json.value);
 },
 });
```

products/id/code redirects using .htaccess to index.php

index.php contains:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$val = $data->value;
Save to file...
```

This works for POST/DELETE/PUT.

How do I make it work for a GET request.  I have tried

```
$parameters = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $parameters);  
$results = print_r($parameters, true); 
save to file ...
```

but all I get is:

```
Array
(
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

UPDATE:

Seems there is a problem with parse_str($_GET,$parameters).

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] returns:

```
[{%22name%22:%22mydata%22,%22value%22:%22myvalue%22}]
```

When I do a str_replace for [, ] and %22 on the string I get

```
Array
(
    [{"name":"mydata","value":"myvalue"}] => 
)
```

in my saved file.  Is there a more efficient way to strip out these characters?

Comment: is your rewrite writing in the query string into the new url and if so is it assigning it to a variable? like `index.php?q={json}` or `index.php?{json}`

Comment: Get requests does not support data being sent as request body, only POST and PUT requests supports this type of data transfer

Comment: @arunpjohny it appears as though he might be able to get away with it if he sets `processData:false` in the `$.ajax` request

Comment: @Orangepill but as per the spec GET does not have an entity body right http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: with the jquery docs it states that the data is encoded as part of the url so it wouldn't make an appearance in the body. the parseData flag would prevent jquery from trying to encode it as per a normal get request. i.e. `key=value&key2=value...`

Comment: he should be able to get at it with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` after doing that

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
parse_str($_GET, $parameters);
```